# jQuery timer keeps on rolling after page change using Ruby on Rails and Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having the following problem with a timer in my Rails app that uses jQuery and Turbolinks: I have a `setTimeout` timer running on my start page for an image slide. When I click a link the page changes, but the timer keeps on rolling, which I think is somehow caused by Turbolinks. Also, when I re-enter the start page it triggers the timer again and stacks on the old one.

I've been playing around with `clearTimeout` (e.g., trying to place it on different places), but I can't get that working. I would like to be able to see if there's a `setTimeout` running and then stop it before starting a new one, or something like that...

This is the timer I have on my start page:

```
var timerSplash = setTimeout(splash, 5000);
```

I'm really in a dead end now and I need help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
if (window.timerSplash)
   clearTimeout(window.timerSplash);

window.timerSplash = setTimeout(splash, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I had to put the clearTimeOut code in my application.js file and then the actual setTimeout code in a page specific Javascript file to get this really working, but eventually I got the right combination.